# GWT Designer can't find GWT module X in project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gwt-designer, ivyde

I am having trouble with GWT Designer in my GWT application.

```
Can't find GWT module
    GWT Designer can't find GWT module com.google.gwt.query.Query in project. Possible reasons: 

    1. There really are no module with this ID. For example, it was just mistyped or accidentally broken. 
    2. Jar files or project that contains the required module is not included into the classpath of the current GWT project. 

Show stack trace. 
Hide stack trace. 

Stack trace:

org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 4000 (Can't find GWT module). com.google.gwt.query.Query
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.check.Assert.isTrueException(Assert.java:390)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.ModuleVisitor.accept(ModuleVisitor.java:141)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.ModuleVisitor.accept(ModuleVisitor.java:190)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.ModuleVisitor.accept(ModuleVisitor.java:190)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.ModuleVisitor.accept(ModuleVisitor.java:115)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.Utils.getFileForResource(Utils.java:642)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.Utils.getFilesForResources(Utils.java:628)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.Utils.getFileForResource(Utils.java:602)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.Utils.getHTMLFile_web(Utils.java:998)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.Utils.getHTMLFile(Utils.java:945)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.util.Utils.getDocType(Utils.java:804)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.model.widgets.support.GwtState.initialize(GwtState.java:166)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.parser.UiBinderContext.createGWTState(UiBinderContext.java:467)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.parser.UiBinderContext.createProjectClassLoader(UiBinderContext.java:328)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.model.EditorContext.createClassLoader(EditorContext.java:146)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.parser.UiBinderContext.createClassLoader(UiBinderContext.java:285)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.model.EditorContext.initialize(EditorContext.java:100)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.parser.UiBinderParser.parse(UiBinderParser.java:105)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.uibinder.editor.UiBinderDesignPage.parse(UiBinderDesignPage.java:56)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:451)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.access$2(XmlDesignPage.java:443)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage$7$1.run(XmlDesignPage.java:417)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage$7.run(XmlDesignPage.java:414)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(XmlDesignPage.java:435)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(XmlDesignPage.java:388)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:252)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:85)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.XmlDesignPage.setActive(XmlDesignPage.java:171)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.xml.editor.AbstractXmlEditor.pageChange(AbstractXmlEditor.java:652)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3080)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1772)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

It says that it can't find this module package anywhere. I am able to compile via ANT without any issue at all and I am using IvyDE dependency management for my external library management.

[image]
This is a basic overview of my project package structure and the error message too. The libraries are all there is just seems like GWT Designer isn't able to see them.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on here? I have tried to get this working and nothing is working. Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't initialize Browser

GWT Designer uses a web-browser to render the GWT UI using the WebKit framework. During initialization, the WebKit engine returned: 3: Cannot resolve proxy hostname ().

The solution to your problem is:

Your Project misses the file gwt-dev.jar. Add it in buildpath and restart your eclipse IDE.